# GeofencingClient take lot of time in adding the geofences

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services, android-geofence

I have a feature that depends on GeoFencing Technology There is a weird problem. On adding a Geofence, the client takes a lot of time to add *(Have a look at logs)*. This is weird as it works pretty well earlier (no code change related to location and all afaik) without any delay.

I am using the following dependency:

> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

```
@RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    fun addGeoFences(
            geoFences: ArrayList<Geofence>,
            onSuccess: () -> Unit = {},
            onFailure: (Exception) -> Unit = {}
    ): Boolean {
        if (isAddingGeofence) {
            GlobalLoggerUtils.showLog(TAG, "isAddingGeofence: $isAddingGeofence")
            return false
        }
        GlobalLoggerUtils.showLog(TAG, "addGeoFences()")

        if (geoFences.size == 0) {
            return false
        }
        isAddingGeofence = true

        geoFencingClient
                .addGeofences(
                        getGeoFencingRequest(geoFences),
                        geoFencePendingIntent
                ).addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                    isAddingGeofence = false
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    isAddingGeofence = false
                }
                .addOnCanceledListener {
                    isAddingGeofence = false
                }
        return true
    }



2019-05-30 12:43:29.716  I/: addGeoFences() 
2019-05-30 12:44:00.602  I/: isAddingGeofence: true 
2019-05-30 12:44:02.424  I/: isAddingGeofence: true 
2019-05-30 12:44:03.525  I/: isAddingGeofence: true 
2019-05-30 12:44:04.975  I/: isAddingGeofence: true 
2019-05-30 12:44:06.541  I/: isAddingGeofence: true 
2019-05-30 12:48:18.384  I/: add success >>> result: null  
2019-05-30 12:48:18.393  I/: add success >>> requestIds: XYZ
```

Let me know if there anything required to add in context to this problem. Adding the Geofence is as per the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing).

Edit #1: *05 June 2019*

> Looks like this happen in development build only. Works fine in
>   release build installed from play store.

Answer (score 0):

If it's Android 8.0+, be aware that there is a background location restriction that also applies to the Geofencing API[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits#apis)

Comment: Thanks Loius for the answer. But I am aware of that and is not what is asked for. I have a problem with long delay/waiting time in adding the geofence not waiting for the event(s).